# TS object; rollapply(), lm() regression:

Tags: r, time-series, regression

First post here. Trying to run a rolling linear regression on a time series: code is as follows

```
MX_data <- merge.zoo(as.zoo(MX_tr),as.zoo(MX_RER_2))
```

MX_tr and MX_RER_2 are ts objects with 37 rows. the value for width below, w, is a vector that defines the length of my desired windows on which regressions will be calculated

```
w<- c(4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5)


rollingbeta <- rollapply(MX_data,
                 width= w,
                 FUN = function(Z) coef(lm(formula=MX_tr~MX_RER_2, data = 
as.data.frame(MX_data))),
                 by.column=FALSE, align="right")
```

the result i get gives me a matrix looking object with two columns, one for the intercept and one for the Beta term. Problem is that every value in each column is the same: -1.14 for the beta term, and 0.0866 for the intercept. These are the values i get from running the regression on the whole series.

help is much appreciated. thanks

Comment: You do not define `Z` in here `function(Z) coef(lm(formula=MX_tr~MX_RER_2, data = 
as.data.frame(MX_data)))`

Comment: Please review [mcve].

Comment: I see. I thought z took on the value of MX_data as the first argument in the rollapply function. n